# GPS ligado, mas não funciona mais no APP

Tags: android, gps

td bem?
Seguinte, estou implementando um código de GPS no meu APP. Ele estava funcionando tudo normalmente até então, até a hora que eu testei desligar o GPS do celular - pra ver se ele dava erro no APP mesmo. Só que quando eu ativei o GPS do celular de novo, é como se o meu aplicativo não reconhecesse mais o GPS.

Pra todos os efeitos, segue ae meus códigos:

arquivo **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtLatitude, txtLongitude;
    private String latitude, longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLat);
        txtLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLong);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 124);

        GPSTracker g = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
        Location l = g.getLocation();

        if(l != null){

            double lat = l.getLatitude();
            double lon = l.getLongitude();

            if(latitude == null && longitude == null) {

                latitude = String.format("%.8f", lat) + "\n";
                longitude = String.format("%.8f", lon) + "\n";

            }else{

                latitude = latitude + String.format("%.8f", lat) + "\n";
                longitude = longitude + String.format("%.8f", lon) + "\n";

            }

            txtLatitude.setText(latitude);
            txtLongitude.setText(longitude);

        }else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro na captura!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

}
```

Lembrando que no meu AndroidManifest.xml eu tenho certinho a permissão setada:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Conto com a ajuda de alguém, por favor.

Obrigado!!! :-)

Comment: Dá o erro que está no `Toast` ? Apanha valores que estão incorretos ? O que aparece no LogCat ?

Comment: Perdão gente!!! Fui testar meu código fora do meu local de trabalho, e ele funcionou perfeitamente. Fui dar uma olhada mais a fundo em códigos de GPS e percebi que o ponto que ele capta não é sempre muito preciso, às vezes ele muda alguns metros a cada vez que eu mando capturar o resultado ... falei besteira ou procede? :-)